# AOSP Android 13: aptx Adaptive not supporting?

Tags: android-source

Why `aptX Adaptive` codec is not available in Developer Options > Bluetooth Codecs in AOSP based Android 13 ROMs, though device supports it? Though it is available in Android 12 based AOSP roms?

Answer (score 1):

For the framework part to work, the vendor needs to be working correctly. It is the first pre-requisite that the vendor image has the libAptX and related libraries ported from the stock images. Since Qualcomm/OEM is actually shipping them on the device, you would have to pull them from the stock images.